# SQL Developer: Why can't I select by column synonym?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just created a column synonym

`CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM col_syn FOR X_CHILD.FIRST_NAME;`

This was executed without error.

But when i say

`select dob, col_syn from x_child;`

I get this:

```
ORA-00904: "COL_SYN": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 13
```

The column "first_name" for sure exists:
`select * FROM x_child;`
shows:
[image]

I've pressed commit at least 18 times and restarted SQL developer. This did not help.

Also, when I click on synonyms in this schema, there's nothing there. And the only synonym i can see is the table synonym. Am I supposed to be able to see the column synonym here too?

[image]

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401) says that you can create synonyms _for a table, view, sequence, operator, procedure, stored function, package, materialized view, Java class schema object, user-defined object type, or another synonym_. Column is not mentioned,

Comment: @PonderStibbons - you beat me to it!  But I was able to reproduce a 'successful' CREATE SYNONYM on a column, just like the OP.  So I guess the real question is why does oracle not return an error on that?

Comment: Oracle doesn't validate the referenced object. Perhaps they wanted to allow you to create synonyms in advance for things you will define later. It also doesn't remove the synonym if you drop the object, so arguably it's just being consistent. `create synonym nonsense for hatstand.banana;` runs fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A synonym, which is an alternative name for a table, view, sequence, procedure, stored function, package, materialized view, Java class schema object, user-defined object type, or another synonym. **You cannot have a synonym to a column**

Synonyms provide both data independence and location transparency. Synonyms permit applications to function without modification regardless of which user owns the table or view and regardless of which database holds the table or view. However, synonyms are not a substitute for privileges on database objects. Appropriate privileges must be granted to a user before the user can use the synonym.

When you create the synonym in your example, the reference object does not need to exist at all. In your case

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM col_syn FOR X_CHILD.FIRST_NAME;
```

you are creating a public synonym ( available for everybody ) which makes a reference to the object X_CHILD ( that is why you have in your dba_synonyms as reference_name X_CHILD ) and as reference_type TABLE ( not column )

Specify the schema to contain the synonym. If you omit schema, then Oracle Database creates the synonym in your own schema. **You cannot specify a schema for the synonym if you have specified PUBLIC.**

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-SYNONYM.html#GUID-A806C82F-1171-478E-A910-F9C6C42739B2